# How to push a view using textFieldDidBeginEditing event?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield

I want to push a view when I tap on a textfield, and I use the method textFieldDidBeginEditing
to do it. The thing is that my navigation controller crashes someway that when I try to go back to the view when the textField is, the navigation bar seems to pop back, but the view that should be popped, stays.

On the other hand, I want the textField not to rise the keyboard, because I think thats one of the problems here.

I would appreciate any comments.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You said that it crashes- do you receive any error messages in the console?

Using an UITextField as a view pusher is difficult and probably goes against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines, is there some important reason you can't use a UIButton or UITableViewCell?

Comment: There is no error in the console, and maybe you are right  about Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.
In fact the textfield is inside a UITableViewCell, is just a custom cell with a label and the textfield. I used to have a button, and it works good, but I removed it to get some extra space.